# Using Expression to Hide Certain Data in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I'm trying to hide/suppress data using an expression for Row Visibility in SSRS.
I currently have an expression:

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,True,False)
```

That hides certain data I do not want to appear, but I would like to add an additional field to hide as well.

I tried adding an additional values with:

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,True,False
Or CInt(Fields!MobileType.Value)<>1,True,False)
```

Used "Or" and "And" to make it work neither does. Any suggestions on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2,True,IIF(CInt(Fields!MobileType.Value)<>1,True,False))
```

or

```
=IIF(CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)=1 Or CInt(Fields!EM_ET.Value)= 2 Or CInt(Fields!MobileType.Value)<>1,True,False)
```